# curl fails to correctly send headers

Tags: php, curl

My initial project was of checking whether a certain Apple ID exists or not, I have proceeded doing this in php by navigating to apppleid.apple.com/account/ and pretending to register an account with all the fields blank except the account field, and if I got an error it meant the account existed, otherwise If I got other errors but not an "account exists" error I would return false. However I have encountered a few problems on the way. The first was that you need to preserve all the headers/cookies on the way (which I did) but it still does not work, and apparently always answers with "1". The code can be found here : [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/xbLdELbP). Please follow the link and try to solve this problem, I really need this done. Thank you very much whoever got some time to read this post.

**EDIT**
code:

```
<?php
require("simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php");

$input = get_data('https://appleid.apple.com/account');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($input);

//echo $input;
$table = array();
foreach($html->find('input') as $inn)
{
        $val = "";
        try
        {
                $val = $inn->getAttribute('value');    
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
                $val = "";
        }
        //echo $inn->getAttribute('name') . $val . "\n";
        if($inn->getAttribute('name') != "" && $inn->getAttribute('name') != "account.name")
        {
                $table[$inn->getAttribute("name")] = $val;
        }
        if($inn->getAttribute('name') == "account.name")
        {
                $table[$inn->getAttribute("name")] = "naclo3samuel@gmail.com";
        }
}
$NIX = http_build_query($table);
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
$ch = curl_init();
$hs = get_headers("https://appleid.apple.com/account", 0);
$headers = $hs;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://appleid.apple.com/account/");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($NIX));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $NIX);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
//close connection
curl_close($ch);



/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5000;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: please post the code in the question and not link to it.

Comment: guys, this is a really urgent matter, if anyone can fix this please do, I don't care if you downvote my question but please contribute. Your help will be heavily credited.

Comment: Seriously, you post a question, containing "please follow the link and solve my problem", within a minute add a comment asking us to "please answer", and you edit it to insult your audience calling them lazy. I'm not even going to read a single line of your code.

Comment: we are the lazy ones ? bahahahaha

Comment: You're getting my close vote, not an answer.

Comment: It was just a joke, but okay. Fine I edit my question D:

Comment: Why do you have to troll me instead of answering a question? No one seems to care...

Comment: I'm at work coding for a paying client, you insult us and expect instant help - you reap what you sow

Comment: @Dagon Ok, I appologize to everyone, I have edited the question. Stop commenting about the matter please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the problems is right here: `get_headers("https://appleid.apple.com/account", 0);`

This will return something like:

```
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[1] => Date: Sat, 29 May 2004 12:28:13 GMT
[2] => Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
[3] => Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
[4] => ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
[5] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
[6] => Content-Length: 438
[7] => Connection: close
[8] => Content-Type: text/html
```

What is cURL supposed to do with that? This is not in a format acceptable by `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and neither headers a Server would expect from a Client request.

I suppose you are trying to stablish Cookie session. I recommend you do all that without use of `get_headers()` or putting your finger in the headers at all.

Enable cURL's Cookie support by setting the options `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`, make a call to `https://appleid.apple.com/account` to initialize your Cookies, and then do the rest.

Example:

```
$cookies = tmpfile();

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://appleid.apple.com/account/",
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookies,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookies,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true
]);
curl_exec();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $NIX
]);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$hsize = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = explode("\r\n", substr($result, 0, $hsize));
$result = substr($result, $hsize);
```

Comment: Thanks! you put me in the right direction, looking that up now.

Comment: but I need to get the Headers too a lot of them matter.

Comment: There. Now you have the response headers and the response body.

Comment: Remember to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` if you are having issues with cURL and `https://`.